# How to display a table using AJAX in modal?

Tags: php, html, ajax

### officer_cashier.php

This is my modal form I want to display a table upon clicking the button `add`  from `cashier_template.php` in DIV tag `id=add_table`

```
<div class="modal fade" id="fee_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
        aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Process payment</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close get_close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form method="POST" action="officer_cashier.php" id="reg">
                             <fieldset class="scheduler-border">
                                <legend class="scheduler-border">Student information</legend>
                                <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="id" name="id">  
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="name">Name</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" readonly="readonly">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="course">Course</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="course" name="course" readonly="readonly">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="sem">Semester</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="sem" name="sem" readonly="readonly">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="year">Year</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="year" name="year" readonly="readonly">
                                </div>
                            </fieldset>
                            <button class="btn btn-sucess add_fees" id="add_fees">add</button >
                            <div class="form-group" id="display_table"></div><!-- I want to display the table inside of this DIV tag -->
                        </form>
                  </div>
              </div>
         </div>
     </div>
```

### script

This is my AJAX the `course,sem,year` data is what i need to display the table, so if those three fetch successfully I want to display it in my DIV tag `#display_table`

```
$(document).on('click', '.add_fees', function(){  
 $.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "../templates/cashier_template.php",
    data: {
        "course": $("#course").val(),
        "semester": $("#sem").val(),
        "year": $("#year").val(),
    },
    success: function(data) {
        $("#display_table").html(data);
    }
});
});
```

### cashier_template.php

This is the cashier template once the AJAX pass the data and matcher the query it should display in modal but I wasnt getting

```
    <?php
    ob_start();
    include("../include/userlogin.php");
    if(!isset($_SESSION)) 
    { 
        session_start(); 
    } 
    if($_SESSION['usertype'] != 1){
        header("location: login.php?success=1");
        $_SESSION['message'] = "You cannot access this page unless you are a officer!";
    } 
    ob_end_flush();
    $yearId = $_POST['year'];
    $courseId = $_POST['course'];
    $semesterId = $_POST['semester'];

    $result = $connect->query("SELECT id, total_fees, fee_names FROM manage_fees WHERE year_lvl = '$yearId' AND course = '$courseId' AND semester = '$semesterId'") or die($connect->error());
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()):
?>
        <div class="table-sorting  table-responsive" style="margin-top: 1rem;">
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="table1">
                <thead>
                    <tr class="p-4">
                        <th scope="col">Select</th>
                        <th scope="col">School fees</th>
                        <th scope="col">Amount</th>
                        <th scope="col">type</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <?php 
                        $result = $connect->query("SELECT * FROM fees;") or die($connect->error());
                        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){ 
                    ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td>              
                            <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                            <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input check_amount" name="local_fees">
                            <label class="custom-control-label" for="check_amount"></label>
                        </div>
                        </td>
                        <td name="selected_fees"><?php echo $row['fee_name']; ?></td>
                        <td name="amount"><?php echo $row['amount']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['type']; ?></td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php } ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<script src="../js/datable.js"></script>
```

Comment: What's the problem with all that code? What have you tried to resolve the problem? Also, be warned that your SQL query is widely open for injections - please have a look at prepared statements

Comment: @NicoHaase yes mate i've tried the code above the problem is, the table is showing once i click the `button add_fees` but instead it show the data at the top of `navbar` at the same time the modal was close

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5741187)

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the `$result` object (and subsequently the `$row` obect) when you query `fees`. So the big loop at the top:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()):
```

is getting overwritten down the line by

```
 $result = $connect->query("SELECT * FROM fees;");
 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
```

But really, there's no need to query `FEES` in every loop. Why not first get all the fees data into an array, then just access it in the other loop. So first, at the top of your php script:

```
<?php 
$fees=array();
$result = $connect->query("SELECT * FROM fees;");
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){ $fees[]=$row; } 
?>
```

Then in your main loop

```
<?php 
foreach ($fees as $fee) {
?>
...
<td name="selected_fees"><?php echo $fee['fee_name']; ?></td>
<td name="amount"><?php echo $fee['amount']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $fee['type']; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
```